# Windows 10 1607 appears to ignore WSUS and related GPOs

Tags: windows-update, group-policy, wsus

We've recently re-enabled WSUS after it previously caused all kinds of mayhem prior to installing the Anniversary Edition of Windows 10 Pro. However, on my test box, it doesn't seem to be fully paying attention to either the GPO in place for configuring updates, or the WSUS server itself.

From what I can tell, it tries to talk to the WSUS server, but then seems to just go and pull the updates from the web anyway, which is obviously not what we wanted it to do. Equally, the GPO was configured to have the updates install at a specific time, and then restart later - but it's simply not installing them unless you do so manually. As the idea behind this is that the computers would update overnight and be ready to go in the morning, this is somewhat less than ideal!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Windows 10 1607 is no longer supported.